# What collection do I need to store an Object and it's quantity?

Tags: java, collections

I need to store the Product (Object), and it's quantity in a Collection, where I will be able to increase the quantity of each product whenever needed.

What Collection type will work and is best to use in this case?

Comment: It depens on your further requirements, but I would first try a HashMap

Comment: If you need to search the product to update the quantity, then use HashMap and define proper equals and hashcode also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), for example a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). The map key should be the key of the product and the value is the quantity of the product.

Comment: The key could be the `Product` object itself.

Answer (score 1):

If the quantity is simply a count, and if you're open to using a third-party library, you could use a `Bag` from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections). A `Bag` is a `Collection` that is unordered and allows duplicates. Internally, a `HashBag` is usually implemented with a `HashMap`, with keys associated to their counts. In the case of `HashBag` in Eclipse Collections, the backing store is an `ObjectIntHashMap`. This has the advantage of not having to box and unbox the `Integer` objects as you might if you map keys to their counts in a `java.util.HashMap`.

```
Product product1 = Product.of("abc");
Product product2 = Product.of("xyz");

MutableBag<Product> counts = Bags.mutable.empty();

counts.addOccurrences(product1, 5);
counts.addOccurrences(product2, 10);

Assert.assertEquals(5, counts.occurrencesOf(product1));
Assert.assertEquals(10, counts.occurrencesOf(product2));
```

Here is a [blog](https://medium.com/oracledevs/bag-the-counter-2689e901aadb) that describes `Bag` in more detail.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections